# Unrecognized selector in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions with topViewController assignment

Tags: iphone, ios

What is causing this?  I am running iOS 5.1 on Xcode 4.3 and using Storyboards.

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WFTopTableViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d56f80'


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    // Initial view controller is a Table View Controller, so we look up the window's rootViewController.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    // Set up the controller.
    WFTopTableViewController *controller = (WFTopTableViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    // Pass the controller the managed object context for the first time.
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks!
Amanda

Comment: Unless WFTopTableViewController is a subclass of UINavigationController, that code ain't gonna fly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    WFTopTableViewController *controller = (WFTopTableViewController*)self.window.rootViewController; 
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext; 
    return YES; 
}
```

The rootViewController of your window is already the WFTopTableViewController, not a UINavigationController. If you want it the other way around, make sure you select the 'Is Initial View Controller' option for the UINavigationController in the Interface Builder.